# unable to enable button on row selection

Tags: javascript, button, odata, sapui5

The idea is to enable button on selection of a row. But when i selecting any row the button is not getting enabled.

Please find  code snippet and screenshot [error_1] as attached

```
     onInit: function () {
        var oViewModel,
            iOriginalBusyDelay,
            oTable = this.byId("table");

        // Put down worklist table's original value for busy indicator delay,
        // so it can be restored later on. Busy handling on the table is
        // taken care of by the table itself.
        iOriginalBusyDelay = oTable.getBusyIndicatorDelay();
        // keeps the search state
        this._aTableSearchState = [];

        this.oSemanticPage = this.byId("page");
        this.oEditAction = this.byId("editAction");
        oTable.attachSelectionChange(this.onTableSelection, this);
    },

    /* =========================================================== */
    /* event handlers                                              */
    /* =========================================================== */
    onTableSelection: function () {
        var oTable = this.getView().byId("table");
        var aSelectedItems = oTable.getSelectedItems();

        if (aSelectedItems.length > 0) {
            this.byId("test").setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Controls that are repeated multiple times (e.g. in a Table or List) should not have IDs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to get the Button and manipulate its enable/disable property. Try to use a model and change the model property accordingly. This is how MVC works.

```js
    selectionChange: function() {
      oModel.setProperty("/btnEnabled", this.getSelectedItems().length > 0);
    }
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/rexeyaf/edit?js,output

Comment: hello Seah, i tried doing this but it is not working. i am getting error as "Uncaught TypeError: this.getSelectedItems is not a function" . please see the error attached.